# django map form field to another key

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

django form is,

```
In [55]: class my(forms.Form):
    ...:     abc_pqr = forms.CharField()
```

Request data is `{'abc-pqr': 'data'}`.

I want to map `abc-pqr` key  to `abc_pqr` form field, how do I achieve this without changing request data ?

Comment: what does your view look like?

Comment: what about save() method?

Comment: why you don't want to change in request data, give explanation?

Answer (score 0):

```
request_data = request.POST;
request_data['abc_pqr'] = request_data.get("abc-pqr")
```

Comment: thanks, but as I already mentioned without changing request data.

Comment: u can try this also `form.instance.abc_pqr= request_data.get("abc-pqr")`

Comment: Please share View Code also